# Custom error message for jQuery validation on radio button group

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, radio-button

I'm using the below code for combo box group validation and it shows *This field is required.* as the error message. How can I modify the below code to customize the message. Thanks in advance.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    

    $('input[name="batches.batch"]').rules("add", "required");//works fine
    $('input[name="batches.batch"]').messages("error message1", "error message2");// no effect

});
```

My html :

```
    <input name="batches.batch" type="radio" value="" />First <br />
    <input name="batches.batch" type="radio" value="" />Second<br />
    <input name="batches.batch" type="radio" value="" />Third<br />
    <input name="batches.batch" type="radio" value="" />Fourth<br />
```

Libraries I'm using :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which are you using, jquery-validate or jquery-validation-engine? Your code looks like jquery-validate.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using jquery-validate.

Comment: It's not working because this plugin contains no such method called `.messages()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code...

```
$('input[name="batches.batch"]').rules("add", "required");//works fine
$('input[name="batches.batch"]').messages("error message1", "error message2");// no effect
```

It's not working because there is [no documented method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) called `.messages()`.  Methods have to be created by the plugin developer in order to be available.

Instead, `messages` goes inside of your `rules('add')` method, like this...

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate();

    $('input[name="batches.batch"]').rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "my custom required message"
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rDcDW/**

The above works great for *dynamically adding rules*, however, if you just need to [workaround the `name`'s with dots issue](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29), simply declare the rules as normal but use quotes around the `name`...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            'batches.batch': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'batches.batch': {
                required: "my custom required message"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/YZs3Y/**

Comment: The demo at [ http://jsfiddle.net/YZs3Y/]( http://jsfiddle.net/YZs3Y/) is working fine. but the posted answer is not working. Thank you so much for the demo code.

Comment: @VisruthCV, I posted two totally different methods and they both are working fine as demonstrated by each jsFiddle.  Can you elaborate more about what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#formid").validate({
    rules: {
        batch: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        batch: { required: "Customized error message" }
    }
 });
```

Comment: It's not working. I have updated my question, can you look at it again please!!!!